# How to sort items alphabetically?

Tags: angular, sorting, typescript1.8

I'm trying to sort a list of fullname in a dropdown list as for example :
list ==>

- Patric Moo
- Faro eto
- Cancello Rettin
- Adriano molin-ret

here i want to create a pipe to order that list and in my html part i'll need just to use the pipe in the select option as : | sortAlphabetically
How to implement that ?
i found this example for one letter :

```
   @Pipe({name: 'AlphabeticSortPipe'})

   export class AlphabeticSortPipe implements PipeTransform {

   transform(value: any[]): any[] {
   value.sort(function(a, b) {
    const alc = a.toLowerCase();
    const blc = b.toLowerCase();
  return alc > blc ? 1 : alc < blc ? -1 : 0;

   });

  console.log(value);
  return value;

  }
  }
```

but this pipe is for only one letter. How to sort these name ? thank you everyone !

Comment: that pipe its not for only one character, a and b are reference to two values of array passed as argument to this pipe,after transformed toLocaleLowerCase, returning string comparacion. Do you tried to verify that only works to a single character?

Answer (score 2):

Use `localeCompare()`

```js
transform(value: string[]): string[] {
  // Use a copy of your array if you want to keep the original untouched
  return [...value].sort((a, b) => {
    a = a.toLowerCase(); // or a.toLocaleLowerCase()
    b = b.toLowerCase(); // or b.toLocaleLowerCase()
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  }
}
```

You can add a parameter to the `transform()` function to sort by ascending or descending

```js
transform(value: string[], ascending = true): string[] {
  // Use a copy of your array if you want to keep the original untouched
  return [...value].sort((a, b) => {
    a = a.toLowerCase(); // or a.toLocaleLowerCase()
    b = b.toLowerCase(); // or b.toLocaleLowerCase()
    return ascending ? a.localeCompare(b) : b.localeCompare(a);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this solution should works too.